# React: avoid unnecessary re-renders of child components (with callback prop) when parent re-render too often

Tags: reactjs

Parent component receive props data(exists in redux and are different every second) which cause re-renders.How to avoid unnecessary re-renders of Child component?
React.memo does not work because callback is different every time

```
class Parent extends React.Component { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: '',
    };
  }

 shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return (!isEqual(nextProps.data, this.props.data)
          ||  !isEqual(nextState, this.state));
  }

 onChangeHnadler = (e) => {
  this.setState({value: e.target.value})
 }

 render () {
  const { value } = this.state;
  return (
   <Child value={value} onChange={this.onChangeHnadler}/>
  );
}

const Child = React.memo(({value, onChange}) => {
 return <input value={value} onChange={onChange}/>
});
```

Comment: Is this a watered down example? I don't see how the `onChangeHandler` would be different each render of `Parent`. The child is just an input. This may be too simplified to understand your issue and how to rectify it.

Comment: @Drew Reese  data exists  in redux and are different every second

Comment: I see, so the `data` updating causes the parent to rerender, a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `memo` compare function, the second parameter passed to `memo` HOC. I'm assuming the `value` prop is more stable? You can hint to react to try and skip rerenders if

```
const areEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  return prevProps.value === nextProps.value;
};

const Child = React.memo(
  ({value, onChange}) => <input value={value} onChange={onChange}/>,
  areEqual
);
```

**Note**

> This method only exists as a **performance optimization**. Do not rely on
>   it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs.